# Share cookies between sessions in IE7

Tags: cookies, internet-explorer-7

I'm trying to get IE7 to share its cookies between sessions.  I found that if i set the expiration date, it will share the cookies.  However, i can't use this method because i am trying to control login to my application (users may only login once).  Is there another way to get IE7 to share?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know cookies aren't bound to session, but to the browser i.e. different sessions can read the same cookie (on the same domain).
A better way to check if a user is allready logged in would be a flag in the database, since users who really want to log in more then once can use different browsers...